# How to reset NoUiSlider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reset, nouislider

How can i reset all sliders in particular form using javascript? (jquery also acceptable) http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Answer (score 5):

Read the [Setting slider values](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/#section-setting) section:

```
// Set one .noUiSlider.setue
slider.noUiSlider.set(10);
slider.noUiSlider.set([150]);

// Set the upper handle,
// don't change the lower one.
slider.noUiSlider.set([null, 14]);

// Set both slider handles
slider.noUiSlider.set([13.2, 15.7]);
```

Comment: I know this way, it is not what i'm looking for. I want to reset many sliders at once. Is it possible?

Comment: This will set, not reset, new values. The difference is important because sometimes you don't want the 'set' and 'update' events to be fired. For instance when you have many sliders and you want to reset all but the one the user is playing with.

Comment: @RegularEverydayNormalGuy Create a new question and ... Is it a question or a suggestion?

Comment: This is a statement explaining why your solution does not answer the "How to *reset* NoUiSlider?" question.

Comment: @RegularEverydayNormalGuy Would you like to improve it?

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781910/how-to-reset-all-other-nouisliders-but-the-one-the-user-is-playing-with

Answer (score 4):

A little late, but the link of [Praveen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31269981/1166642) pointed me to the right direction.

Inside the [noUiSlider-Reference](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/reference/) it mentions the reset-method, which reset the slider to its start-value(s), which was exactly what I was looking for:

```js
    // Return to the 'start' values
    // Does NOT reset any other slider properties
    slider.noUiSlider.reset()
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with NoUISlider v7.0 (I know there is a newer one) and this is how I resolved it :

Given the following markup :

```
<div class="container">
    <label>Price</label>
    <div class="slider" data-min="100" data-max="900000" data-step="1000"></div>
    <input type="hidden" class="input-filter-min" value="100" />
    <input type="hidden" class="input-filter-max" value="900000" />
    <span class="filter-min"></span> - <span class="filter-max"></span> €
</div>
```

And the following initialization :

```
$('.slider').each(function() {
     $(this).noUiSlider({
            connect: true,
            behaviour: 'tap',
            start: [100,900000],
            step: 1000,
            range: {
                'min': 100,
                'max': 900000
            }
        });
});
```

To destroy and re-initialize (after click somewhere or action of yours) :

```
$('.slider').each(function() {
        $(this)[0].destroy();
        $(this).parent().find('span[class^="filter"]').text('');

        var min = parseInt($(this).attr('data-min')), max = parseInt($(this).attr('data-max'));

        $(this).parent().find('.input-filter-min').val(min);
        $(this).parent().find('.input-filter-max').val(max);
    });    

    setNoUiSliders(); // which is a function that do the basic initialization in the previous example
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<sliderName>.noUiSlider.reset();
```

If you have multiple sliders, follow by implementing loop as:

```
var sliderName = ["A","B","C"];
for(var i=0; i<sliderName.length; i++){
  sliderName[i].noUiSlider.reset();
}
```