# How to reset all other noUiSliders but the one the user is playing with?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, nouislider

I have multiple sliders, each of them linked to form fields. When any of them gets updated, either by dragging or typing, I want to reset all the others.

The reason for this is that I want the user to save his changes to one slider (form) before he tries to change another. Else, I reset the changes.

I can't listen to the `update` or `set` events and call `.set()` on the other sliders, because that would trigger an endless loop.

So how can I reset a slider without triggering any event? Or anyone has a different approach?

(adding code as requested)

```
slider.noUiSlider.on('set', function(values, handle) {
    $(slider).parents('form').siblings('form').find('my-slider').each(function() {
        var values = this.noUiSlider.get();
        var originals = $(this).closest('.mirror-field').toArray();
        values.forEach( function(val, index) {
            if ( ! val.isSame(originals[index].value)) { // val is a 'moment' object
                values[index] = originals[index].value;
            }
        });
        this.noUiSlider.set(values); // this is when chaos is unleashed
    });
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

try using "slide"

```
SLIDER1.noUiSlider.on('slide', function(){
    SLIDER2.noUiSlider.set( *defaultvalue* );
    SLIDER3.noUiSlider.set( *defaultvalue* );
    ...
});
```

"slide" doesn't call the `.set()` method but works somehow the same as "update"

maybe this is your solution :)

Comment: sorry, made a typo the first time, now it should work :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's a little bit more complicated though (I've added more info to the question). The 'slide' event is not triggered when the slider changes programmatically, as it is the case when you link the handles to form fields.

Comment: I believe I really need to listen to the 'update' or 'set' events, but I need to find a way to update (reset) the other sliders without triggering these events.

Comment: Oh okay, alright. Could you provide a little bit of code?